# Is it possible to set a struct property as undefined or null?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, storage, struct

In JavaScript we're able to have:

```
Object {
 a: number;
 b?: string;
 c: number;
 d?: string;
}
```

b and d being optional, these can be left out during variable initialisation. Is this possible in solidity? Is it possible to do something similar like:

```
struct test {
 address a;
 uint256 b;
 bytes32 c;
 address d;
}

// Initialisation: 
test newTest = test({
 a: address(0),
 b: 1,
 c: bytes32(0),
 d: address(0)
});
```

So only the b property has a sensible value in newTest. The rest can be left out. Is this legal? I would think it's not best practice, what would be a better alternative?

My intended purpose:
I have a CQRS-ish type of interaction between my dapp and contract where a function in a contract would take an action with a payload, the payload can be of different types. The object is passed as a struct, with it, assigned is the type of action, and the payload assigned to one of the properties in the struct with the correct data type.

Comment: It's not only legal but it's the default value, so just leave those fields untouched.

Comment: Why did you delete your two other questions, which I gave you help with (in particularly the one to which I provided a formal answer)??? It will just make me think twice whether I should make any effort on your questions here next time I see one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but yes.

The important thing to realize is that storage is laid out to accomodate the structs you defined. Not setting means they will retain their initial values, 0x000... according to type and length (i.e. false, 0, length=0, etc.).

In practice, you don't need to write 0's, but you will be unable to instantiate a partial instance.

This will not compile:

```
test newTest = test({
 a: address(0)
});
```

However, this will work:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract NullVals {

    struct Test {
        address a;
        uint256 b;
        bytes32 c;
        address d;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => Test) public tests;

    function silentSetter(bytes32 key, address a) public {
        Test storage t = tests[key];
        t.a = a;
    }

}
```

Note that I used a mapping, in storage to hold instances, since the `struct` defines a type only. When you recall something only partially set, you will see the other values do indeed exist with their default values.

Hope it helps.